# What is the meaning of "[*.]" in the Chrome cookie exceptions dialog?

Tags: google-chrome

[image]
*Screenshot of the add-to-cookie-whitelist pop up (chrome://settings/cookies?search=cookies)*

I am always entering the metacharacters `[*.]` here, what is their meaning? Do i correctly guess that `[]` means *zero or one*, `*` means *one or more letters from "a" to "z"*, and `.` means the literal "."?

(some 300+ points owner: would you be so kind to append *metacharacter* to the tags of this question and then delete this paragraph?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you're mostly correct about `*` and `.` on their own (but note that domain names are *not* limited to just letters a-z), this doesn't quite apply to the `[ ]` part.

The pattern is meant to *look* like "zero or one", as in the common convention of using […] to mark something as "optional". However, within Chrome, **only** the exact string `[*.]` is recognized by the pattern parser, and only if it's located at the beginning of the "host" part. The brackets have no meaning in any other case; e.g. `[abc.]def` will not be recognized.

If the prefix `[*.]` is present at the beginning of the "host" part of the URL, the pattern will match both the specified domain and its subdomains. In other words, it's as if you had the two patterns:

```
example.com
*.example.com
```

Comment: Thats great, so i can now replace the entries `[*.]chess.stackexchange.com` and `[*.]unix.stackexchange.com` with just `[*.]stackexchange.com` ^^

Comment: Do you have a code/doc/whatever reference where google defines this?

Comment: See common_settings_pattern_parser.{h,cc} at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/components/content_settings/core/common/

Comment: [There](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/components/content_settings/core/common/content_settings_pattern_parser.cc#15) it is! (but not for long probably)